# Rounding up 5-min data to a complicated hourly basis

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have my data as below:

```
Timestamp   Outbound Utilization (%)
11/22/2017 9:55 12.356965
11/22/2017 10:00    14.4424725
11/22/2017 10:05    19.44614625
11/22/2017 10:10    49.3823
11/22/2017 10:15    51.21698
11/22/2017 10:20    50.67409188
11/22/2017 10:25    14.89324375
11/22/2017 10:30    27.1916175
11/22/2017 10:35    19.8268025
11/22/2017 10:40    9.996577813
11/22/2017 10:45    7.929271875
11/22/2017 10:50    22.7705
11/22/2017 10:55    32.611105
11/22/2017 11:00    9.761414375
11/22/2017 11:05    13.10104375
```

My date column should be rounded up to hourly data, but it should look like 10:05, 11:05, which means all data from 9:05 to 10:05 should be accumulated and shown as 9:05, 10:05 to 11:05 data should be shown as 10:05, something like this, does floor/round function work on this, or do we need to implement our own logic

Comment: Do you need average or sum of data for each of the hour?

Comment: @keipa, Mean :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, convert `Timestamp` to `datetime` -

```
df['Timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Timestamp'], errors='coerce')
```

Now, set `Timestamp` as the index and call `resample` with a `base` argument which specifies the offset from the beginning of each hour -

```
df.set_index('Timestamp').resample('60min', base=5).sum()

                     Outbound Utilization (%)
Timestamp                                    
2017-11-22 09:05:00                 26.799437
2017-11-22 10:05:00                315.700051
2017-11-22 11:05:00                 13.101044
```

If you're looking for the average, call `mean` instead of `sum` -

```
df.set_index('Timestamp').resample('60min', base=5).mean()

                     Outbound Utilization (%)
Timestamp                                    
2017-11-22 09:05:00                 13.399719
2017-11-22 10:05:00                 26.308338
2017-11-22 11:05:00                 13.101044
```

If want to reset the index, you can add a `reset_index` on the result.